# SQL referring on one table after join with another table

Tags: mysql, join

I got this MySQL query to output latest chat message a user with ID of 18 has had with other users. The query works until I add-in last `JOIN`, intended to calculate amount of unviewed msgs (`unviewed_total`). The error I get is 'column not found' for `T2.rid1` and `T2.rid2`. Can't figure out how to refer these columns in a proper way.

```
SELECT T2.maxDate, T2.ava, T2.uname,chat.user_to,chat.user_from,chat.body,chat.request_id,chat.secondary_rid, T3.unviewed_total FROM 
                (SELECT T1.user2_id, users.uname, users.ava, max(cdate) maxDate, T1.rid rid1, T1.sec_rid rid2 FROM
                (SELECT chat.user_to user2_id, max(msg_time) cdate,request_id rid,secondary_rid sec_rid
                    FROM chat WHERE chat.user_from=18
                    GROUP BY chat.user_to
                union distinct
                (SELECT chat.user_from user2_id, max(msg_time) cdate,request_id rid,secondary_rid sec_rid
                    FROM chat WHERE chat.user_to=18
                    GROUP BY chat.user_from)) T1
                inner join users on (users.uid = T1.user2_id)
                group by T1.user2_id
                order by maxDate desc) T2
            join chat on (T2.maxDate = chat.msg_time)  
            join (SELECT COUNT(viewed) unviewed_total FROM chat WHERE viewed='0' AND user_to=18 AND request_id IN (T2.rid1,T2.rid2)) T3
            ORDER BY T2.maxDate DESC
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner query of that join doesn't know about the table T2.
I suggest moving the join to the select statement.

Change

```
SELECT T2.maxDate, T2.ava, T2.uname,chat.user_to,chat.user_from,chat.body,chat.request_id,chat.secondary_rid, T3.unviewed_total FROM
```

to

```
SELECT T2.maxDate, T2.ava, T2.uname,chat.user_to,chat.user_from,chat.body,chat.request_id,chat.secondary_rid, (SELECT COUNT(viewed) unviewed_total FROM chat WHERE viewed='0' AND user_to=18 AND request_id IN (T2.rid1,T2.rid2)) unviewed_total
```

More about this technique here: https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-server-20-using-subqueries-in-the-select-statement/

Comment: Thank you, it works well. And a separate big (!) thanks for the link which pretty much explains it